# PowerShell - Conversion error when inserting into SQL table

Tags: sql-server, powershell, datetime

I'm importing a CSV file and inserting the data into a SQL table. However, I'm facing a convert issue due to data quality issues.

> ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

The field contains both dates in the format `20191206` and `NULL` values.

The insert statement for this column appears like so `convert(varchar, @Column9, 112)`. I've tried various different date formats and casting, but I always receive this error! What can I do?

Comment: Date (and time) data types don't have a format in SQL Server, so if can't be in the format `yyyyMMdd`. **Strings** can be in that format, but considering you have the expression `convert(varchar, @Column9, 112)` then `@Column9` is clearly not defined as a `varchar`.

Comment: I'm inserting into a string into a datetime field in SQL. I'm declaring the column a varchar using $c9 = $cmd.Parameters.Add("@Column9",   [System.Data.SqlDbType]::varchar, 20)    as this is how I've had to manage a similar issue previously.

Comment: Why are you declaring `@Column9` as a `varchar` and converting is to a `varchar`? That achieves nothing. `CONVERT(varchar(25),'1234567890',112) = '1234567890'`. There is no point converting a `varchar` to a `varchar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input is a text, and the destination column is a datetime type?
Then TRY to convert the string.

A [TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) or [TRY_CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql) will return NULL when the conversion fails.

So try this:

```
TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, @Column9, 112)
```

Or:

```
TRY_CAST(@Column9 AS DATE)
```

If the destination column is a VARCHAR/NVARCHAR?
Then COALESCE to the original value if the conversion fails.

```
COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, @Column9, 112), 21), @Column9)
```

Or:

```
COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, TRY_CAST(@Column9 AS DATETIME), 21), @Column9)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Still receiving the error "Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a DateTime."

Comment: What's the type of the column that will receive the value? Is it a datetime or datetime2 or smalldatetime or date?

Comment: It's a datetime column.

Comment: @Fler Updated. Well, it'll return null's for the failed conversions instead of errors.

Comment: Thanks Luk, the 'TRY_CAST' appears to do the job! I do get an error when I first run the script though: Cannot convert null to type "System.DateTime". Do you know what may be causing this?

Comment: Not sure, I don't see errors in [this test](https://rextester.com/MRUIR8120).  You'll probably have to figure out what that input string is that causes that error. Or maybe that DATETIME has the NOT NULL defined?  Then you could COALESCE to a default date like '1900-01-01'

Comment: No problem. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

reading through the lines, and the comments here. You state the definition of `@Column9` is as follows:

```
$c9 = $cmd.Parameters.Add("@Column9", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::varchar, 20)
```

This means that the statement `convert(varchar, @Column9, 112)` is completely pointless; converting a `varchar` to a `varchar` does nothing (even with a style code). Style Codes are when converting to or from a `varchar`. For example when converting from a `date` to a `varchar` or from a `varchar` to a `varbinary`; they do nothing when both sides are a `varchar`.

I suspect what you actually want is `CONVERT(date,@Column9,112)`. If that fails, you aren't passing a **string** of the format `yyyyMMdd`. but really, you should be passing a `date` datatype from Powershell in the first place and not converting the value in your SQL.

Comment: As per the last comment on my question 'I've tried various different date formats and casting, but I always receive this error! What can I do?'. I've tried the above, it didn't work. The string is in the format yyyyMMdd.

Comment: It clearly isn't  @Fler , if the above fails. `SELECT CONVERT(date,'20191206')` works fine. if you can't replicate this issue for us, we can't help you. `yyyyMMdd` is non-ambiguous so unless the date is invalid (like `'20191131'`, which would give a different error) then what you are passing is not what you think.

Comment: I'm not being condescending at all, @Fler, I'm stating a simple fact; `yyyyMMdd` is non-ambigous and will never generate the error you describe (regardless of data type, or language settings). The error is a SQL error, not a Powershell error, thus this clearly points at the value being passed, from Powershell. This isn't condescending, it's just simple elimination of possibilities.